# Paypal request payment works in sandbox but not production

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments

I'm trying to generate a PayPal payKey to use with the [PayPal lightbox payment](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/ht_ap-embeddedPayment-curl-etc/#lbox) option.  The code below works perfectly well against the sandbox -- it returns a payKey.  However, when I switch the credentials (and URL) to point to the production PayPal site, I get an `Internal server error. Please check the server logs for details`.  No other information is being returned.  How can I debug this issue?

```
import requests
import urlparse
import json

_ppuserid_ = "zzz_api1.zzz.zzz"
_pppassword_ = "zzzzz"
_ppsignature_ = "zzzzzzzz"

_ppappid_ = "APP-80W284485P519543T"
_ppendpoint_ = "https://svcs.sandbox.paypal.com/AdaptivePayments/Pay"

def __get_standard_headers__():
    return {'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-USERID': _ppuserid_, 
               'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-PASSWORD': _pppassword_,
               'X-PAYPAL-SECURITY-SIGNATURE': _ppsignature_,
               'X-PAYPAL-REQUEST-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
               'X-PAYPAL-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON',
               'X-PAYPAL-APPLICATION-ID': _ppappid_}

def get_paypal_pay_key(returnUrl, cancelUrl, paymentAmount):
    '''Create a pay request. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/'''
    headers = __get_standard_headers__()

    jsondata = {
            'actionType':'PAY',
            'clientDetails': { 'applicationId' : _ppappid_ },
            'currencyCode':'USD',
            'memo':'Product 001',
            'receiverList': { 'receiver' : { 'amount': paymentAmount, 'email': _ppreceiveremail_, 'paymentType': 'DIGITALGOODS' }},
            'requestEnvelope': { 'errorLanguage': 'en_US' },
            'returnUrl': returnUrl,
            'cancelUrl': cancelUrl,
        }

    jsonObj = json.dumps(jsondata)

    r = requests.post(_ppendpoint_, headers=headers, data=jsonObj)

    parsed_response = r.json()

    if parsed_response.get('responseEnvelope'):
        if parsed_response.get('responseEnvelope').get('ack') == 'Success' and parsed_response.get('paymentExecStatus') == 'CREATED':
            #Payment was created, return the pay key
            return parsed_response.get('payKey')

    return 'ERROR'
```

EDIT: I also retrieved the headers of the production response (as a Python dictionary), in case this is helpful to determine the cause:

```
{'Content-Length': '76', 'X-PAYPAL-OPERATION-NAME': 'Pay', 'X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-NAME': '{http://svcs.paypal.com/types/aa}AdaptiveAccounts', 'X-PAYPAL-ERROR-RESPONSE': 'TRUE', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'X-EBAY-SOA-REQUEST-ID': '152a7963-e700-a101-8644-d108fff16e1a!AdaptiveAccounts!10.16.24.100![]', 'Server': 'Apache', 'Connection': 'close', 'Paypal-Debug-Id': 'c31f40fb798e2', 'X-PAYPAL-SERVICE-VERSION': '1.0.0', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Set-Cookie': 'X-PP-SILOVER=name%3DLIVE9.APIT.1%26silo_version%3D880%26app%3Dadaptiveaccountsapiserv%26TIME%3D4212240982; domain=.paypal.com; path=/; Secure; HttpOnly, X-PP-SILOVER=; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT', 'Date': 'Wed, 03 Feb 2016 14:43:07 GMT', 'CACHE-CONTROL': 'no-cache, max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'X-EBAY-SOA-RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT': 'JSON', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL': 'NONE'}
Internal server error. Please check the server logs for details
```

Comment: i'm having the same problem with the php api

Comment: @astroanu I gave up on PayPal's API and opted for [Braintree](https://www.braintreepayments.com) PayPal processing instead. I'm still waiting for them to link my PayPal account, but so far integration has been much more straightforward. PayPal's documentation was just horrible.